# jQuery to Replace Table Elements with Bootstrap Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to replace all my tables with divs in order to make their columns stackable in Twitter Bootstrap. This way people can still use Tinymce in the backend to easily create tables, but they won't break the responsive design. Zurb Responsive Tables just doesn't cut it.

The issue is that bootstrap divs are based on total width of 12 columns (span5, span7 etc) so the div classes would need to change whenever a table had more or fewer columns. I'm thinking I need a JS that can count the number of columns in the table and then replace those with divs of the proper classes while reordering the content. So for example, for a two column table the classes would be "span6". For a four column table they would be "span3." The Table tag being replaced with a div of class "row"

This is way beyond my JS knowledge, can anyone lend a hand or have a more elegant solution that still allows for easy backend editing in the wysiwyg?

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do this. Here is a sample code:

```
var table = $('table'),
    div = $('<div />');

$('td', table).each(function(){
    $('<div />').html($(this).html()).appendTo(div);
});

table.after(div).remove();
```

And demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tkirda/7GM5w/